# Mathematically choose the better discount

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations

This may seem like a homework problem because it is. However it is not my homework - it belongs to the child I am tutoring, so please feel free to give a full answer, as I will only lead the child along with it and not just fill the answers for him.

The question:

> Two stores offer discounts on a particular class of products (let's
>   say laptops). One store offers a discount of 30% off for every hundred
>   dollars you spend. The other offers a 20% discount on your total.
>
> Where should you buy your laptop?

The answer is obviously it depends. Clearly, for prices in even multiples of hundreds, the first offer (30% off every hundred) is far better, but for steps of 100 in \$99 (\$99, \$199, \$299 ....), the second offer is better. And they are equal at steps of 50, as in \$150, \$250, etc.

But how do you represent all this as a mathematical formula? How can you mathematically solve which is better?

I suppose the equations would look something like

$$\frac{7}{10}x + y, \space \space \space \space \space \space \frac{4}{5}(x+y)$$

where $x$ is the multiples of $100$ and $y$ is the number of $1$s.
But where do you go from here?

Comment: After a (short) while the first is always better. A *single* formula is of limited usefulness.

Comment: @ Andre, for practical price ranges of a laptop, total discount is better all the time.  I am trying to find the breakeven ( you call it flip between choices) within this practical range, but could not find it

Comment: In symbols, let the price be between $100n$ (inclusive) and $100(n+1)$ (exclusive). Discount 1 is $30n$, Discount 2 is $\lt 20(n+1)$. So 1 is better than 2 if $30n\ge 20(n+1)$, that is if $n\ge 2$. So only issue is with $[100,200)$, easy.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

Draw out the equation for a price range from 100 to 4000 in increments of 100 and workout the discounted Price, you will find that the 20% discount on the total would be worse than the 30% on every 100 dollars.  Chart out the equations in EXCEL  and calculate for different prices and compare them.  You will find the result self evident as you see below.

[image]

Comment: The After Discount 1 column does not look right. Mental calculation is more reliable.

Comment: I edited it and the flip point happens right at $200.  Andre cannot be wrong!!.  Thanks for noticing.